# my local cisco devices to backup on my local lappy as tftp server in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server

**strong text*
cat /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa

## !/bin/sh

#### BEGIN INIT INFO

## Provides:     tftpd-hpa

## Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog $network

## Required-Stop:    $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog $network

## Default-Start:    2 3 4 5

## Default-Stop:     0 1 6

## Short-Description:    HPA's tftp server

## Description:      Trivial File Transfer Protocol (TFTP) is a file transfer

## protocol, mainly to serve boot images over the network

## to other machines (PXE).

#### END INIT INFO

PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
DAEMON="/usr/sbin/in.tftpd"

test -x "$DAEMON" || exit 0

NAME="in.tftpd"
DESC="HPA's tftpd"
PIDFILE="/var/run/tftpd-hpa.pid"
DEFAULTS="/etc/default/tftpd-hpa"

set -e

[ -r "$DEFAULTS" ] && . "$DEFAULTS"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
    # Ensure --secure and multiple server directories are not used at the
    # same time
    if [ "$(echo $TFTP_DIRECTORY | wc -w)" -ge 2 ] && \
       echo $TFTP_OPTIONS | grep -qs secure
    then
        echo
        echo "When --secure is specified, exactly one directory can be specified."
        echo "Please correct your $DEFAULTS."
        exit 1
    fi

```
# Ensure server directories exist
for d in $TFTP_DIRECTORY
do
    if [ ! -d "$d" ]
    then
        echo "$d missing, aborting."
        exit 1
    fi
done

start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec $DAEMON -- \
    --listen --user $TFTP_USERNAME --address $TFTP_ADDRESS \
    $TFTP_OPTIONS $TFTP_DIRECTORY
```

}

do_stop ()
{
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --name $NAME
}

do_reload ()
{
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --name $NAME --signal 1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        init_is_upstart > /dev/null 2>&1 && exit 1

```
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;

stop)
    init_is_upstart > /dev/null 2>&1 && exit 0

    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;

restart|force-reload)
    init_is_upstart > /dev/null 2>&1 && exit 1

    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    sleep 1
    do_start
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;

status)
    status_of_proc $DAEMON $NAME
    ;;

*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
```

esac

---

$ sudo systemctl status tftpd-hpa
● tftpd-hpa.service - LSB: HPA's tftp server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-05-04 13:17:46 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6838 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start (code=exited, status=0/SUC

May 04 13:17:46 virendra systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HPA's tftp server...
May 04 13:17:46 virendra systemd[1]: Started LSB: HPA's tftp server.
lines 1-8/8 (END)

Comment: And what's the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 sudo apt install tftpd-hpa
```

create directory `/tftp`

```
 sudo mkdir /tftp
 sudo chmod 777 /tftp
```

then edit `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` to like above

```
vi /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure -c"
```

Then restart service

```
sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
```

Allow access in `UFW`

```
sudo ufw allow 69
```

After that you can go to `cisco` and copy config to tftp